# How to put multiple JS elements into one group

Tags: javascript

I'm making a page where one action affects multiple elements. What I'd like to do is label each element as being part of the same group/class, so I can have a function act on any element with that label. Right now I'm using getElementById, and each element has to have a unique identifier. Rather than give each function a separate action for each element, I'd prefer to have one action and tell it to act on any element with a particular label. Here's what I have now:

```
<script>
function C1on()
{
element=document.getElementById('C1p');
  {
  element.src="ring.png";
  }
element=document.getElementById('C1c');
  {
  element.src="ring.png";
  }
}
</script>
```

Calling that with:

```
<td><img id="C1p" onmouseover="C1on()"
onmouseout="C1off()" src="blank.png" width="63" height="63"></td>
```

So instead of just telling it to look for anything labeled "C1" and do this action to it, I have to call each of those "C1" elements separately. getElementsByClassName seems like what I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to get that to work. I just want short, simple, clean code, and I know that what I have right now has to be doing it wrong.

Comment: Prepare for the flood of *You should use jQuery!* responses..

Answer (score 3):

this is what classes are for

```
document.getElementsByClass('class_name').addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
    event.target.src = "ring.png"
}, false);
```

with html:

```
<img class="class_name"/>
```

Comment: I think `getElementsByClass` returns an array you'd have to loop through.  Also, it's IE9+ (as well as grown-up people browsers)

Comment: So, does that code block replace the entire script, or just what's in the script, or just what's inside the function? When the user mouses out of the image, will it return to what it was originally, or should I still use a separate mouseout script?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I have `<script>
function C1on()
{
document.getElementsByClass('class_name').addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){event.target.src = "blue.png"}, false);
}
</script>` to change to an image on mouseover, and `<script>
function C1off()
{
document.getElementsByClass('class_name').addEventListener("mouseout", function(event){event.target.src = "blank.png"}, false);
}
</script>` to go back on mouseout. I'm trying to call that with `<img class="C1" src="blank.png" width="63" height="63">`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you've encapsulated these bindings within functions.  Do you ever call the functions?  AddEventListener says: anytime mouseover or mouseout happens, perform the following so you have to run AddEventListener before the user starts interacting with the page.  If you just define functions and don't run them, then the browser doesn't know what you want to happen when those events occur.

Comment: Good point. Where do I put the suggested listeners? In a script without a function? Not in a script? In the head or body? Or is the problem that I still have to call the functions in the html?

Comment: I don't know what that means. Where should I put this code? Is there anything else that needs to be included? No one's explaining what each part of that code does or what it needs, so maybe listing a complete chunk of code would be helpful? The reason I'm asking this question here is because I don't already know how to do it. :)

Comment: Any more suggestions on where to put listeners, where to put document ready, and what that whole part should look like? Is document ready a jQuery thing? I've never used that.

Comment: It sounds like you are very early on in your learning.  One of the keys to becoming a competent program is learning how to find answers to your questions.  You're asking the right questions and if you google for them and look through other SO questions.  Unfortunately I can't answer every question you have through the comment section of this SO post.  Sorry.

Comment: The whole reason I asked here is because all the resources I could find through Google were along the same lines of "you need this code snippet, good luck figuring out how to use it, what each part of it means, or where to put it."